Designing a Teaching Innovation Study for Slow Learners in Civil Engineering
I am an Assistant Professor of Civil Engineering. I have recently been tasked by the Department Chair to design a teaching innovation study with the focus to support and enhance the academic performance of slow learners, specifically targeting students with a CGPA of 5 to 7 on a 10-point scale.
I don't have any prior experience in designing a study of pedagogical nature, I am reaching out for advice and pointers on how to approach this.
Are there any resources, such as books, articles, or websites that you would recommend for someone new to designing educational studies? Any insights, experiences, or resources would be incredibly helpful.
I've searched for articles using keywords like 'slow learners', but most of the literature I found focuses on elementary school students or non-engineering courses.

sounds like an worth while project, but your question is a shopping question and off topic for this site. Perhaps try looking for "Engineering education research" (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_education_research) or "engineering pedagogical research" to refine your search.

This is a resource question, not a shopping question @RichardErickson.

Search for "Pedagogical Patterns". There is a lot of activity in that community, directed at effective teaching in general, but mostly in STEM education.

What is the purpose of your "study"? Is it simply to understand slow learners or do you really want to find and implement effective pedagogy?

Being a bit suspicious by this point in my life, this sounds like some sort of trap, with intentional or not...

Are they actually slow learners vs unmotivated vs juggling too many courses vs who knows what??? The approach would likely be different for these and other scenarios.

@Buffy we want to find and implement pedagogy for slow learners, implement for two semesters and monitor changes in academic performance

@JonCuster They are slow learners with low motivation. They do not have any more courses than other students in their class.

@user3024069 - so you have declared them as such and will stick by your label. And, should they not respond to your attempt, what will you call them next? Teaching is hard, people learn in many different ways for many different reasons. Perhaps redesigning the original courses to benefit a broader range of learning styles would be the first step.

Contact the education department in your university, or perhaps the teaching excellence center. If you have no background in designing studies and interventions, you will do about as good a job as if someone suggested you do a study of old English history.
In other words, get in contact with the experts and ask for their help. Perhaps even ask your department head to make this connection for you.

There is no education department or teaching center. That's why I'm struggling
